# Determine the YouTube channel URL from the v3 data APIs

Tags: ruby, youtube, youtube-api

Using the YouTube data APIs (v3) only, I would like to generate a URL for a youtube channel. There doesn't seem to be a way to generate the channel URL from a channel resource alone. The documentation for a channel resource is here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource

At the moment we are still using the v2 data apis to get the username, which we can then use to construct the URL using the username (which not all channels have) returned: 
http://www.youtube.com/user/USERNAME

Want to make sure we are not overseeing something obvious here before we log a feature request.

Note: we can generate a URL for the Google+ page if the accounts are connected, but we want to show the youtube channel URL instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an url for the channel using "id", from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource

```
http://www.youtube.com/channel/id, where id needs to be replaced.
```